# Disable the option to scroll outside the md-dialog in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I have the following dialog configuration:

```
var position = this._mdPanel.newPanelPosition()
    .absolute()
    .center();

var config = {
    attachTo: angular.element(document.body),
    controller: PanelDialogCtrl,
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    disableParentScroll: this.disableParentScroll,
    templateUrl: 'tmp',
    hasBackdrop: true,
    panelClass: 'form-dialog',
    position: position,
    escapeToClose:true,
    trapFocus: true,
    clickOutsideToClose: false,
    focusOnOpen: true,
    locals:{ }
};

this._mdPanel.open(config);
```

But when I scroll outside the popup it is scrolled. I want the dialog fixed to the position without any movement or something outside.

setting `hasBackdrop: false` doesn't working.

Comment: what's the value of `this.disableParentScroll`?

Comment: Fixed by set disableParentScroll: true
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to disable scroll outside of your modal, set `disableParentScroll` option to true.

```
$mdDialog.alert()
    .disableParentScroll(true)
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PRaVMR)